# Unable To Install Unirest via Python

Tags: python, pip, unirest

I keep trying to install unirest, but I'm unable to do it. I'm using python 3.4 because I couldn't figure out how to install it on 2.7. Even though I'm in the 2.7 directory, I think it is running python 3.4. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this? Is there a manual way? I've tried searching for a while and can't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the connection is timing out. Might be the server is down or slow. Try changing the time allowed before time-out (`--default-timeout=60` or so.) You should also be able to just download the unirest source and install that locally using `pip` or the Windows installer: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unirest/

Comment: ok thx..  i managed to install it, however, now i'm getting a new error .i don't even know what this is saying, is it missing or not missing now?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9zeGuSd.png

Comment: I upgraded my comment to an answer; since it fixed your problem, please accept it. :) As for your new error, it sounds like you need to install another module named `poster`. Try `pip install poster`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the connection is timing out. Might be the server is down or slow. Try changing the time allowed before time-out (`--default-timeout=60` or so.) You should also be able to just download the unirest source and install that locally using pip or the Windows installer: pypi.python.org/pypi/Unirest